# Calculate tf-idf in Gensim for my vocabulary

Tags: python, gensim, tf-idf

I have a set of words (n-grams) where I need to calculate tf-idf values. These words are;

```
myvocabulary = ['tim tam', 'jam', 'fresh milk', 'chocolates', 'biscuit pudding']
```

My corpus looks as follows.

```
corpus = {1: "making chocolates biscuit pudding easy first get your favourite biscuit chocolates", 2: "tim tam drink new recipe that yummy and tasty more thicker than typical milkshake that uses normal chocolates", 3: "making chocolates drink different way using fresh milk egg"}
```

I am currently getting tf-idf values for my n-grams in `myvocabulary` using sklearn as follows.

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary = myvocabulary, ngram_range = (1,3))
tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(corpus.values())
```

However, I am interested in doing the same in Gensim. Forall the examples I came across in Gensim;

1. uses only unigrams ( iwant it for bigrams and trigrams as well)
2. calculated for all the words (I only want to calculate for the words in `myvocabulary`)

Hence, please help me to find out how to do the above two things in Gensim.

Answer (score 0):

In gensim, for a dictionary, you should use `gensim.corpora.Dictionary` class, look at [examples](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html#from-strings-to-vectors)

Unfortunately, we have no support ngrams in general, only bigrams for words with [Phrases](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html) class

Comment: Can you tell me how to calculate tf-idf using bigrams? bigrams are enough for me at the moment :)

Comment: 1. Process you text
2. Fit Phrases + apply it to text (gives new text with bigrams)
3. Calculate tfidf with TfidfModel

Comment: That is the question I have. How to input the selected bigrams I want to calculate tf-idf to the tfidfmodel :D

Comment: Look at example for phrases https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html .


You apply phrases to your dataset -> get new dataset with bigrams -> use this as input for tfidf

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I figured out how to use Phrases. But calculating tf-idf is the issue I am facing now. If you would like I can share my code. Please help me:)

Comment: Is there a way I could increase the number of worker threads for this process? It seems to be fixed at 3.